# UCanAccess: Add column to existing table

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I've got a working Java project which uses an Access .accdb database to store data.
I am working on an update for my program to provide more features for the user.
For this to work I need to add a column to an existing table filled with data.
As I researched I found out that UCanAccess could not support

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD ColumName DataType
```

This is unfortunate, but I understand that since the low level drivers don't support it, UCanAccess can't support it either.

I then found this workaround:

[How to alter table using UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272368/2144390)

but this won't work for me either, because 1. I'm using .accdb and 2. I can't be sure the users have Microsoft Access installed.

Then I had the idea to clone the current Table with 1 extra column, clone all data into it, drop the old one and rename the new one to the Name of the old one. But i don't know how to do this.

Does anyone know a better way or know how to implement my idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jackcess 2.1.5 added the ability to add a new column to an existing table. There are plans to expand DDL support in UCanAccess to enable `ALTER TABLE`, but in the meantime if you update your project to use Jackcess 2.1.5 or later (in place of the earlier Jackcess version in the UCanAccess `lib/` folder) then you can add your column like so:

```java
// use the Jackcess (2.1.5 or later) API directly 
//   to add a column to an existing table
//
// Note: Close any open UCanAccess connection first.
//
com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database db = 
        com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(dbFileSpec));
new com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.ColumnBuilder("newCol")
        .setType(com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DataType.LONG)
        .addToTable(db.getTable("TableName"));
db.close();
```

## Update: January 2017

UCanAccess versions 4.0.0 and above now support `ALTER TABLE`, e.g.,

```java
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN newCol LONG");
```

Comment: This sounds good, can i update the jackcess with UCanAccess still working?

Comment: I'm not aware of any recent changes to Jackcess that would be expected to cause problems with UCanAccess.

Comment: You can now use the 4.0.0 which added those features